# What is the best way to group dates in a column into months in a query

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I group all the dates in a phpmysql database column to become months and use that in a chart ?
The dates are in this format 05/19/2021

I tried using DATEPART() but I am having some errors. I tried to solve it by upgrading using the mysql_upgrade file but to no success.

Comment: First off, the only time you should be using phpadmin is if you are forced to use it due to Plesk via GoDaddy hosting or something like that .  Otherwise if you have actual access to the MySQL server, try MySQL Workbench .. its everything that phpadmin was missing.  Citation for download --> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you are storing dates as strings like "05/19/2021", that's something you should fix.  seems more likely your ui client is formatting them that way though.  (workbench also likes to lie about things like that; suggest you just use the mysql command line client)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXTRACT`

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '2022-10-23 02:09:45')
```

Will display `202210`

Or use `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2035-01-18', '%Y %b') AS extractYearMonth;
```

Will display `2035 Jan`

Finaly if your date column is string then convert it to date with this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('05/19/2021', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

To be:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('05/19/2021', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y %b') AS extractYearMonth;
```

Comment: Date_Format works fine. thank you

Comment: date_format will work but not allow easy sorting